# C++, Lambdas, for_each and memory corruptions

Tags: c++, lambda

Let `Action` be a class with a `is_finished` method and a numeric `tag` property.
Let `this->vactions` be a `std::vector<Action>`

The intent is to iterate the vector and identify those Actions who are finished,
store their tags in a `std::vector<unsigned int>` and delete the actions.

I tried to play with lambdas and  a little and came up with a little 
code that read nicely but caused memory corruptions. The "extended" version,
on the other hand, works as expected.

I suspect foul play in the remove_if part, but for the life of me I can't figure
out what's wrong.

Here's the example code.

**This causes memory corruptions**

```
std::vector<unsigned int> tags;

auto is_finished=[p_delta](Action& action) -> bool  {return action.is_finished();};

//This is supposed to put the finished actions at the end of the vector and return
//a iterator to the first element that is finished.
std::vector<Action>::iterator nend=remove_if(this->vactions.begin(), this->vactions.end(), is_finished);

auto store_tag=[&tags](Action& action)
{
    if(action->has_tag()) 
    {
        tags.push_back(action->get_tag());  
    }
};

//Store the tags...
for_each(nend, this->vactions.end(), store_tag);

//Erase the finished ones, they're supposed to be at the end.
this->vaction.erase(nend, this->vaction.end());

if(tags.size())
{
    auto do_something=[this](unsigned int tag){this->do_something_with_tag(tag);};
    for_each(tags.begin(), tags.end(), do_something);
}
```

**This, on the other side, works as expected**

```
std::vector<Action>::iterator   ini=this->vactions.begin(),
                end=this->vactions.end();

std::vector<unsigned int> tags;

while(ini < end)
{
    if( (*ini).is_finished())
    {
        if((*ini).has_tag())
        {
            tags.push_back((*ini).get_tag());
        }

        ini=this->vaction.erase(ini);
        end=this->vaction.end();
    }
    else
    {
        ++ini;
    }
}

if(tags.size())
{
    auto do_something=[this](unsigned int tag){this->do_something_with_tag(tag);};
    for_each(tags.begin(), tags.end(), do_something);
}
```

---

I am sure there's some rookie mistake here. Can you help me spot it?.

I thought that the `for_each` could be updating my `nend` iterator but found
no information about it. What if it did? Could the vector try to erase beyond the "end" point?.

Comment: is do_something playing with the container at all and therefore invalidating the iterators?

Comment: Not really Michael. I think Casey's answer is right. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::remove_if` does not preserve the values of the elements that are to be removed (See [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove)). Either get the tag values before calling `remove_if` - as you do in the second case - or use [`std::partition`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) instead.

Comment: Thanks Casey, will try that. I misunderstood the documentation when it read that "deleted elements are still referenceable, but with unspecified value" understanding "everything will be there but order can't be guaranteed". I think std::stable_partition is exactly what I am looking for. Will try and check back later.

Comment: Tried it, and was exactly what I was looking for. Answer accepted. Thanks :).